# Detecting keypress is not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, keyboard, key, keypress

I already looked up solutions, but not a single one could help me. I am coding a little snake game, but now I have to detect the user keypress. This is the code I wrote, can someone help me with that?

`

```
        while(running) {


            document.addEventListener("keydown", (event) => { --> Here is the beginning of my           solition
                if(event.keyCode == 68) {
                    right = true
                    up = false
                    down = false
                    left = false
                }
                if(event.keyCode == 83) {
                right = false
                up = false
                down = true
                left = false
                }
                if(event.keyCode == 65) {
                    right = false
                    up = false
                    down = false
                    left = true
                }
                if(event.keyCode == 87) {
                    right = false
                    up = true
                    down = false
                    left = false
                }
            }) ---> Here is the end of my keypress detection, the rest is the code from the game. I am posting it too, maybe I have to change something there.


            if(endMap.includes(pushing) && running) {
                reset();
                running = false;
                document.getElementById("tabelle").innerHTML = "";
                begin();
            }
            if(right && running) {
                if(snakeLength < snakeLengthMax) {
                    list.push(pushing);
                    indOf = list.indexOf(pushing)
                    indOf --;
                    list.splice(list[indOf])
                } else {
                    list.push(pushing);
                    indOf = list.indexOf(pushing)
                    indOf --;
                    list.splice(list[indOf])
                    document.getElementById(pushing-snakeLength).innerHTML = ""
                    snakeLength --;
                }
                pushing ++;
            }
            if(left && running) {
                if(snakeLength < snakeLengthMax) {
                    list.push(pushing);
                    indOf = list.indexOf(pushing)
                    indOf --;
                    list.splice(list[indOf])
                } else {
                    list.push(pushing);
                    indOf = list.indexOf(pushing)
                    indOf --;
                    list.splice(list[indOf])
                    document.getElementById(pushing-snakeLength).innerHTML = ""
                    snakeLength --;

                }
                pushing --;
            }
            if(down && running) {
                if(snakeLength < snakeLengthMax) {
                    list.push(pushing);
                    indOf = list.indexOf(pushing)
                    indOf --;
                    list.splice(list[indOf])
                } else {
                    list.push(pushing);
                    indOf = list.indexOf(pushing)
                    indOf --;
                    list.splice(list[indOf])
                    document.getElementById(pushing-snakeLength).innerHTML = ""
                    snakeLength --;

                }
                pushing -= 21;
            }
            if(up && running) {
                if(snakeLength < snakeLengthMax) {
                    list.push(pushing);
                    indOf = list.indexOf(pushing)
                    indOf --;
                    list.splice(list[indOf])
                } else {
                    list.push(pushing);
                    indOf = list.indexOf(pushing)
                    indOf --;
                    list.splice(list[indOf])
                    document.getElementById(pushing-snakeLength).innerHTML = ""
                    snakeLength --;

                }
                pushing += 21;
            }
            document.getElementById(pushing).innerHTML = "█"
            snakeLength ++;
            await sleep(1000)


        }
        running = true;
```

`

I also tried to put this outside the function, but I didn't know how to detect the key press.
When the key is pressed, the snake should go the other way.

Comment: Small note: [`keyCode` has been deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode).

Answer (score 0):

You might have to click the canvas before pressing your keys.
Newer browsers often don't support keylistening without interaction with the site.

You should also define your variables at the beggining if you didnt already.

```js
let right = false;
let left = false;
let up = false;
let down = false;
```

You might also try changing your keylistener for the following
since event.keyCode is depreciated.

```js
document.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
    if (e.code === "KeyD") {
       right = true
       up = false
       down = false
       left = false
    }
  });
```

Comment: I just clicked everywhere on the site, before clicking and after clicking the keys. Maybe I just understood the answer wrong but if not, it's not working.

Comment: I just changed every "keyCode" to just "code" and it also didn't work.

Comment: Did you troubleshoot with console.log() already to see wether the game even enters the functions?

Comment: Yeah, I also debugged it, it is entering the function but it does not change anything. But I don't know why. Maybe because the Script is running?

Comment: you might alao try to gt the value of your variables at different points throughout the game, sounds like they might not be declared globaly

Comment: But I declared the most of the variables globally. It enters the function when I click W, A, S, or D but it does not enter an if statement

Answer (score 0):

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", (event) => {
  console.log("event key code", event.code);
  switch (event.code) {
    case "ArrowUp":
      // add your logic
      break;
    case "ArrowRight":
      // add your logic
      break;
    case "ArrowDown":
      // add your logic
      break;
    case "ArrowLeft":
      // add your logic
      break;
  }
});
```

You are just changing the state variables inside each direction key press, but instead, you should write a logic to make the snake move. For example if it is moving up, you should bring the head of snake to the next cell or if that is a reward in that cell you should also increase the size of the snake

Answer (score 0):

The one-and-only solution to detect the key the user pressed that **actually works**:

```
document.addEventListener('input', function (e)
{
    const pos = e.target.selectionStart;
    const keyPressed = e.target.value[pos-1];

    // Optional..
    console.log(keyPressed);
});
```

enjoy.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

What is that `while` loop doing? It seems utterly wrong, because it will continually add event listeners.

As remarked `keyCode` is deprecated. Use [event.key](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) instead. Here's a snippet to set one of the four arrow keys to true when pressed (when `running` is true):

```js
const theKeys = {
  up: false,
  down: false,
  left: false,
  right: false
};
let running = false;
document.addEventListener("click", handle);
document.addEventListener("keydown", handle);

function handle(event) {
  console.clear();
  const bttn = event.target.closest(`button`);
  
  if (bttn) {
    running = !running;
    bttn.dataset.running = +running;
    bttn.textContent = running ?
      `disable running` : `enable running`;
    document.querySelector(`[data-display]`)
      .dataset.display = +running;
    return bttn.blur();  
  }

  if (event.type === `keydown` && running) {
    if (event.key.startsWith(`Arrow`)) {
      const theKey = event.key;
      const arrowKeys = Object.keys(theKeys);
      const theProp = theKey.slice(5).toLowerCase();
      //                           ^ length of "Arrow"
      arrowKeys.forEach(key => theKeys[key] = key === theProp);
      //        ^ set theKeys[pressed] key to true, others false
      console.log(`you pressed ${event.key}`);
      return console.log(theKeys);
    }
    return console.log(`${event.key} not an arrow key`);
  }
  return false;
}
```

```css
[data-display="0"] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button id="runningOnOff" data-running="0">enable running</button>

<div data-display="0">Press any key</div>
```